# Installation Steps of Cocos2D for MAC?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to learn about the Cocos2d and I have read more the 3 tutorials on Cocos2D but still I don't have any clearcut idea that how to install Cocos2D on MAC. If somebody knows the proper installation steps of Coco2D, than please give me so that i could start with Cocos2D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

You'll find you need to visit a URL like https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tarball/release-1.0.0-beta-reorder-sprite to get the source, then unzip it wherever you like. Then, as Wenderlich says, you 'Open up a Terminal window to the directory you downloaded Cocos2D to, and enter the following command: ./install_template.sh'.

That's the installation process. When you open XCode, you'll see some new templates to create projects from. The rest of Wenderlich's tutorial shows you how to create a simple Cocos2D game.